# calculation of residuals with numpy lstsq

Tags: python, numpy

I have x,y data:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ 2.5, 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.15625, 0.078125])
y = np.array([ 2448636.,1232116.,617889.,310678.,154454.,78338.])

X = np.vstack((x, np.zeros(len(x))))
popt,res,rank,val = np.linalg.lstsq(X.T,y)
popt,res,rank,val
```

Gives me:

```
(array([ 981270.29919414,       0.        ]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 1,
 array([ 2.88639894,  0.        ]))
```

Why are the residuals zero ? If I add ones instead of zero the residuals are calculated:

```
X = np.vstack((x, np.ones(len(x)))) # added ones instead of zeros
popt,res,rank,val = np.linalg.lstsq(X.T,y)
popt,res,rank,val

(array([ 978897.28500355,    4016.82089552]),
array([ 42727293.12864216]),
2,
array([ 3.49623683,  1.45176681]))
```

Additionally, If I calculate the sum of squared residuals in excel i get `9261214` if the intercept is set zero and `5478137` if ones are added to x.

Comment: Strange. I even get a very slightly different result for the sum of squared residuals in the `ones` case, from the sixth decimal place onwards: array([ 42727293.12864096])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lstsq` is going to have a tough time fitting to that column of zeros: any value of the corresponding parameter (presumably intercept) will do.

To fix the intercept to 0, if that's what you need to do, just send the `x` array, but make sure that it's the right shape for `lstsq`:

```
In [214]: popt,res,rank,val = np.linalg.lstsq(np.atleast_2d(x).T,y)
In [215]: popt
Out[215]: array([ 981270.29919414])
In [216]: res
Out[216]: array([ 92621214.2278382])
```